# Getting syntax error with Union sub query in Sybase DB

Tags: sql, union, sybase

We have a table ta_service with following data

### Ref_id           seq             desc

2340                             1             Service 1
2340                             2             Offer 1
2340                             3             Service 2
2340                             4             Offer 2
2340                             5             Service 3
2340                             5             Service 4

We have a requirement of fetching the services which has offers and we dont have any reference for getting this data apart from Ref_id(foreign key) and seq(Primary key) column.

We tried to fetch by following query but failed with that.

```
SELECT * FROM ta_service
WHERE Ref_id = 2340 AND seq IN ( 
    SELECT seq-1 AS seq
    FROM ta_service
    WHERE Ref_id = 2340
    AND desc LIKE '%Offer%'
UNION 
    SELECT seq AS seq
    FROM ta_service
    WHERE Ref_id = 2340
    AND desc LIKE '%Offer%'
        ORDER BY seq)
```

we are using sybase database. Any help appreciated

Comment: Sybase is a compnay not a database. Which Sybase DB product are you using?  Also please mention the error messages you recieved when trying to run your commands.

Comment: What does the error say? Drop the ORDER BY.

Comment: The error says "The parser detects a syntax error. Click with mouse right button in the input editor of the SQL-Session window or use 'window' menu to activate SQL-Session and have the cursor placed at the error position."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASE doesn't support UNION in any subqueries.

You can refer the [Sybase Documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1510/html/iqrefbb/Convert.htm)

Comment: The documentation you referenced is not for ASE, but for Sybase IQ.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the link to sybase manual which says UNION is not supported in subqueries:
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1570/html/commands/X56548.htm

However I noticed that if we have the union clause within a derived table expression, then, it works fine. Here is the link to sybase manual which gives the syntax for the query:
http://infocenter.sybase.com/archive/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sqlug/html/sqlug/sqlug418.htm

Example of failing and working query given below:

Mocked use case: Get employees from either department D1 or D2.

Failing query:

```
SELECT empname from emp WHERE deptid IN 
(SELECT deptid from dept WHERE deptid = "D1"
UNION
SELECT deptid from dept WHERE deptid = "D2")

Working query:  With additional select and derived table based on union:

SELECT empname from emp WHERE deptid IN (
SELECT deptid FROM 
(SELECT deptid from dept WHERE deptid = "D1"
UNION
SELECT deptid from dept WHERE deptid = "D2") derivedTable
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using ASE, your `ORDER BY` needs to go outside the subquery.

From the [Sybase Documentation:](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1550/html/sqlug/sqlug179.htm)

> •Subqueries cannot manipulate their results internally, that is, a subquery cannot include the order by clause, the compute clause, or the into keyword.

Comment: even after removing the **ORDER BY** clause i am getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove `order by`, and enclose `desc` in `"` because it's keyword

```
SELECT * FROM ta_service
WHERE Ref_id = 2340 
AND seq IN ( 
    SELECT seq-1 AS seq
    FROM ta_service
    WHERE Ref_id = 2340
    AND "desc" LIKE '%Offer%'
UNION 
    SELECT seq AS seq
    FROM ta_service
    WHERE Ref_id = 2340
    AND "desc" LIKE '%Offer%'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

ASE doesn't support UNION in a subquery as the 12.5 SQL manual I've just referred to confirms. It says "You cannot include a for browse clause or a union in a subquery." on page 169 in chapter 5. Another answer is correct even if the link was to IQ. I'd have left a comment but my account doesn't allow it.